# Swift scene kit: move SCNNode to tap position?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, scnvector3

Ok, working with ARKit in Swift here and trying to get a grip on this -

for my game controls I want to be able to control the point (position in 3d space) that the SCNNode is moving towards when the users finger is down on the screen, meaning started by the touchesBegan func.

I want it to be like Apple's fox game with the joystick her but in AR: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Fox/Introduction/Intro.html

My main issue is it doesn't seem that my SCNAction's position to move is being updated correctly on touchesMoved, and moreover I need the SCNNode to move at same speed to the position regardless of how far it is away.

Here's what I have, it is working but not correct:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        let results = sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint])
        guard let hitFeature = results.last else { return }


        checkIfNodeTapped(touches: touches, node: theDude.node)
        theDude.moveToPos(pos: getARPos(hitFeature: hitFeature))
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        let results = sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint])
        guard let hitFeature = results.last else { return }

        theDude.updateWalkTo(pos: getARPos(hitFeature: hitFeature))

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
//        if virtualObjectManager.virtualObjects.isEmpty {
//
//            return
//        }
//        virtualObjectManager.reactToTouchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        //Remove move actions
        theDude.stopMoving()

    }

func updateWalkTo(pos: SCNVector3)
    {
        walkAction = SCNAction.move(to: pos, duration: 1)
    }

    func moveToPos(pos: SCNVector3)
    {
        walkAction = SCNAction.move(to: pos, duration: 1)
        self.node.runAction(walkAction, forKey: "walk")

    }

    func stopMoving()
    {
        self.node.removeAction(forKey: "walk")
    }
```

where the walkAction is just a defined SCNAction. How can I fix this so that the node runs towards wherever the user's finger is on the screen (converted to AR points)?

Comment: "my SCNAction's position to move is being updated correctly on touchesMoved"  What are touchesMoved and touchesEnded for?

Comment: What do you mean? They get the user's current touch position - that works and Ive correctly converted to AR coordinates

Comment: "I need the SCNNode to move at same speed to the position regardless of how far it is away."  Speed = Distance travelled / time taken

Comment: Right, ok I can fix that I forgot simple math.. my fault but moreover the movement doesn't update to the current position even though I'm resetting the action